# Inverting Pairs in Full Duplex RS485

Tags: rs485, serial-bus, duplex

The following is the Full Duplex configuration for a [Maxim 3292](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3291-MAX3292.pdf) RS-485 transceiver module.

**It is possible to invert the polarity of the pairs, lets say, exchange AB by BA and ZY by YZ at the Master end (at the left), without affecting the communication?**

Since I am intending to use an Ethernet Cable with TIA-568A and TIA-568B wiring, with the pair 1 for AB and pair 2 for ZY in TIA-568B at the Master end, I have to use the TIA-568A at the first Slave end, **but inverting the colors of the pairs**, which would be a shame to be so close of the standard configuration.

[image]

Comment: You could in your own environment but interfacing to std networks might be “dyslexic” ;)

Comment: I don't get how using standard CAT wiring would need any pin swaps. Can you be more specfic why do you ask this qustion as why would the use of standard Ethernet cables would need to swap pins of a pair on a single device? If pins are swapped, then it sends/receives wrong polarity of data.

Comment: short answer: no.

Comment: @Justme Just look at the Full duplex configuration, requiring 2 pairs, and the inverting setup from the master (left) to the first slave (left below)... I just expected the TIA-568A and B would solve that, but I realize I would require a TIA-568A with pairs inverted. It do not have anything to do with TIA, but well, that is why am asking....

Answer (score 1):

use pair 2 as YZ instead of ZY.

TIA 568 has pair two (3,6) coloured backwards to make the connector look prettier.